# Removing the period from a hostname

Tags: hostname, vps

My machine's hostname is `ev.er`, and I want to change it to `ever`. I tried editing `/etc/hosts` and replacing `ev` with `ever`, and also replacing `ev.er` with `ever`, saving, and editing the `ev` that was in `/etc/hostname` to `ever`. Then I restarted, but the hostname was still `ev.er` (it shows `ev`).

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Permanent hostname change:

You have to edit the file `/etc/hostname` and change the name of the system and then run:

```
/etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
```

to make the change active. The hostname saved in this file (`/etc/hostname`) will be preserved on system reboot (and will be set using the same script we used `hostname.sh`).

Comment: He said to have changed /etc/hostname and rebooted, which should have made the new hostname apply.